# How to append HTML for every 6 items in array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to generate print-sized pages that hold 6 images each using jQuery and to continue creating these pages until all images in the directory have been gone through.

What I have now is a `var` that holds the HTML string, an array that holds the filenames of each of the files in the directory, and a `$.each` loop that sets the img src to a URL with the filename concatenated to the end of it.

Two questions:

1. As you see below, I have an if / else statement determining the quantity of images by using less than or greater than symbols, but that's not very expandable because if there are more than 18 files in the directory, the code stops. How do I made this loop dynamic?
2. The HTML is appending when I call the append function but it's not adding the changed img source, where am I going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
$('#get-files-btn').on('click', function() {
   
   var html = '<div class="page" style="min-height: 10in; max-height: 10in; min-width: 8.5in; max-width: 8.5in; background-color:green"><div class="row row-cols-2 g-3 mx-3 mt-0"><div class="col mt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-1" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div><div class="col mt-0 pt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-2" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div><div class="col mt-0 pt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-43" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div><div class="col mt-0 pt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-4" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div><div class="col mt-0 pt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-5" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div><div class="col mt-0 pt-0"><img class="img-fluid img-6" src="" ><p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p></div></div></div>'

   $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/public/operations/getFilenames',
      data: {
         get_files: true,
      },
      success: function(response) {
         response = JSON.parse(response);
         let files = [];
         $(response).each(function(index) {
            if (response[index] != '.' && response[index] != '..') {
               files.push(response[index]);
            }
         });

         let count = 0;
         var page_html = $(html).html();
         $(files).each(function(index) {
            
            if (index < 6) {
               console.log(files[index]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-1').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[0]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-2').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[1]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-3').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[2]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-4').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[3]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-5').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[4]);
               $(page_html).find('.img-6').attr('src', 'MY URL/temp/' + files[5]);
            } else if (index >= 6 && index < 12) {
               console.log(files[index]);
               //more code here
            } else if (index >= 12 && index < 18) {
               console.log(files[index]);
               //more code here
            }
         });
         
         $('#pages-col').append(page_html);

      }
   })
})
```

Comment: for sure there's something strange in your each loop over files. The function passed to each will be run for each iteration.. so it's strange that you check the index > 6 and then you set the src attribute for 6 pictures all at once. You should set it only to the currently iterated index.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be perfectly sure I got it right because there are some strange decisions you made in your code. Anyway trying to leave it the same as possible, I put some efforts to integrate the proper render of that file array you retrieve from the ajax request.

This is the core part:

```
//render the files loading the template and setting the src attr of its first 6 images
function renderFiles(files) {
  const basedir = '/temp/';
  const picturesBlock = $('#mytemplate')[0].content.cloneNode(true);
  $(files).each(function(index, file) {
    if (index < 6) {
      $(picturesBlock).find(`.img-${index+1}`).attr('src', `${basedir}/${file}`);
    }
    console.log(file);
  });

  $('#pages-col').append(picturesBlock);
}
```

It's a function that will be called when the `files` array will be ready to process and it will just clone the template `#mytemplate` (I decided to define that long html string you had, as a template, so that it will be easier to mantain) setting the `src` attribute of the 6 images as the url coming from the first 6 positions in the `files` array.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

The callback passed to `each` can accept two arguments (`index`, `value`) so that you can keep track of the index and the value of the current iteration (..for each item in the array).

I also extrapolated the inline styling for `.page` container so that it stays in the css rule reserved for the `.page` selector. You styled the container to have a fixed height and width with a green background.. keep it in my mind if you ask yourself why the `#pages-col` content will overflow its container.

Plus for the sake of the demo I commented out the part doing the ajax request and I just call directly the `renderFiles` function passing a bogus array with 8 filenames. Consider also that I placed the `basedir` value in its own variable inside the function and it will be prepended to the file value when building the src url.

```js
function renderFiles(files, pageSize) {
  const groupsOfFiles = splitIntoGroups(files, pageSize);
    console.log(groupsOfFiles);

  $(groupsOfFiles).each(function(index, groupOfFiles) {
    renderPage(groupOfFiles, 'pageTemplate', $('#pages-col'));
  });
}

function splitIntoGroups(arr, groupSize) {
  let groups = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += groupSize) {
    let group = arr.slice(i, i + groupSize);
    groups.push(group);
  }
  return groups;
}

function renderPage(imageUrls, pageTemplateId, target, basedir = '/temp/'){
  let currentPage = $(`#${pageTemplateId}`)[0].content.cloneNode(true);
  $(imageUrls).each(function(index, file) {
      console.log(`processed url: ${file}`);
      $(currentPage)
        .find(`.img-${index+1}`)
          .attr('src', `/${basedir}/${file}`);
  });
  $(target).append(currentPage);
}

$('#get-files-btn').on('click', function() {

  const files = [
    'file1.jpg',
    'file2.jpg',
    'file3.jpg',
    'file4.jpg',
    'file5.jpg',
    'file6.jpg',
    'file7.jpg',
    'file8.jpg'
  ];
  renderFiles(files, 6);

  /*
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/public/operations/getFilenames',
    data: {
      get_files: true,
    },
    success: function(response) {
      response = JSON.parse(response);
  
      let files = [];
      $(response).each(function(index) {
        if (response[index] != '.' && response[index] != '..') {
          files.push(response[index]);
        }
      });
      //here you should call renderFiles(files);
    }
  });
  */
})
```

```css
.page {
  min-height: 10in;
  max-height: 10in;
  min-width: 8.5in;
  max-width: 8.5in;
  background-color: green;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*this rule was added just to show the contrast between 1st and 2nd page*/
#pages-col > .page:nth-child(even) {
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<template id="pageTemplate">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 g-3 mx-3 mt-0">
      <div class="col mt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-1" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-2" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-3" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-4" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-5" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
        <img class="img-fluid img-6" src="">
        <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center">Description 6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="pages-col"></div>
<button id="get-files-btn">Get Files</button>
```

## A better approach:

This is an even better approach that uses two different templates: one for the page container and one for the single items having the image. This strategy adapts better in case you wish to change the page size or you wish to style the item in general instead of each one according to its position. Of course you can add css rules on top that will address each single `.col` item or each single `.page` like I did in the demo that where I could override the background color of even pages.

This strategy also better deals with the fact that the last group of files might not fill the whole 6 items slot. So instead of having empty images those images won't be rendered at all.

```js
function renderFiles(files, pageSize) {
  const groupsOfFiles = splitIntoGroups(files, pageSize);
  $(groupsOfFiles).each(function(index, groupOfFiles) {
    renderPage(groupOfFiles, 'pageTemplate', $('#pages-col'));
  });
}

function splitIntoGroups(arr, groupSize) {
  let groups = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += groupSize) {
    let group = arr.slice(i, i + groupSize);
    groups.push(group);
  }
  return groups;
}

function renderPage(imageUrls, pageTemplateId, target, basedir = '/temp/') {
  let currentPage = $(`#${pageTemplateId}`)[0].content.cloneNode(true);
  $(imageUrls).each(function(index, imageUrl) {
    console.log(`processed url: ${imageUrl}`);
    renderImage(imageUrl, 'imageTemplate', $(currentPage).find('.row'), index+1, basedir);
  });

  $(target).append(currentPage);
}

function renderImage(imageUrl, imageTemplateId, target, imageIndex, basedir){
  debugger;
  const image = $(`#${imageTemplateId}`)[0].content.cloneNode(true);
  const imageEl = $(image).find('img');
  $(imageEl).attr('src', `/${basedir}/${imageUrl}`)
  $(imageEl).addClass(`img-${imageIndex}`);
  $(image).find('p').text(`Description ${imageIndex}`);
  $(target).append(image);
}

$('#get-files-btn').on('click', function() {

  const files = [
    'file1.jpg',
    'file2.jpg',
    'file3.jpg',
    'file4.jpg',
    'file5.jpg',
    'file6.jpg',
    'file7.jpg',
    'file8.jpg'
  ];
  renderFiles(files, 6);
  
})
```

```css
.page {
  min-height: 10in;
  max-height: 10in;
  min-width: 8.5in;
  max-width: 8.5in;
  background-color: green;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*this rule was added just to show the contrast between 1st and 2nd page*/
#pages-col > .page:nth-child(even) {
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  
<template id="imageTemplate">
  <div class="col mt-0 pt-0">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="">
    <p class="mt-1 mb-1 text-center"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="pageTemplate">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 g-3 mx-3 mt-0">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="pages-col"></div>
<button id="get-files-btn">Get Files</button>
```

Comment: Okay, that works perfectly. How about if I want to call the function for files > 6? I'd like to create a new .page for every 6 images. For example, maybe the directory has 34 images and I want to render 5 and a half pages of images.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. At first you say let's say I want to call the function for files > 6, but later you say you want to render 5. What did you mean here: _" 5 and a half pages of images."_? anyway that callback passed to `.each` will run for every single item inside the array. You could just change the condition `if (index < 6) {`

Comment: The amount of files in the array will always change. I want the function to run for every file in the array no matter the quantity. However, I want each fixed height 'page' to contain only 6 images. If there are more than 6 images, I want to append a new fixed height 'page'. The '5 and a half' refers to the amount of 'pages' 34 images would render.

Comment: I edited my answer so that in the first snippet now it deals with the rendering of multiple pages when fed from a files array arbitrary long. Plus I added a better approach that models the templates with better granularity and enables the opportunity to pick any page size that in the demo was set to 6 elements per page